# Names/salutations for international students of unknown gender

Tags: gender, correspondence

I often receive e-mail (typically inquiring about studying with me as a graduate students) from students, especially foreign students, whose gender/pronouns I can't easily tell (they haven't specified). (For people from the Americas and Europe I can usually guess reasonably reliably, but I get fuzzy when we get to names from Asian/African cultures). Let's say their name is "Foo (given name) Doe (family name)". I normally start formal e-mails "Dear [whoever]".

- Applicants don't typically have a PhD, so I can't address them neutrally as "Dear Dr. Doe"
- "Dear Foo" could work, but I generally like to be a little bit more formal with people I don't know (could argue that the rank differential [professor/prospective student] makes this OK?)
- "Dear Doe" is not a form of address I ever use with anyone else, seems weird
- "Dear Mx. Doe" is unusual in North America (and seems uncommon anywhere outside the UK: ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mx_(title)))
- "Dear Mr./Ms. Doe"?
- Look up the name on the Internet and make a guess based on the region of origin?

Is there a best practice?

Comment: Never guess somebody's title; it's a part of their name, so you should only address somebody by a title they have chosen to be addressed by.

Comment: What's with the formality? If they do come, we'll be on a first name basis. A plain "Hello" is fine.

Comment: "Hello, " works for me

Comment: @kaya3 The only alternative seems to be guessing that they are happy for their title to be omitted.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime If somebody would be unhappy for their title to be omitted, then they should not omit their title when telling you their name. They can hardly complain that you call them by the name they call themselves. If they introduce themselves without giving their title, then you are not merely guessing that they are OK with being addressed without their title; you have evidence they are OK with it.

Comment: For a comparison, I think addressing somebody by a guessed title is as wrong as if somebody introduced themselves to you (in writing) as Alex, and you respond by addressing them as Alexander when their name might be Alexandra, or Alex might not be short for anything. If somebody has given you their name then that's the name you address them by, don't make something else up yourself.

Comment: @kaya3 It has always been normal to sign a letter with one's full name but no title, even in times when omitting a title in reply, or using someone's given name without explicit permission, was unheard of.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says "Mx" is "*accepted* by the UK government." That does not mean it is *commonly used*. I would guess that 99% of the UK population have never used it, and would have to guess what it meant. Compare that with the fact that everybody in the UK knows what "Ms" means.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Assuming you are talking about people who would be unhappy to be addressed without their "Dr." or "Prof." title because that could indicate disrespect, it seems quite normal for people to include such titles in their email signature. In any case, if somebody is upset about being addressed by the exact name that they put in their own email to you, and insists you should address them by their title (which they didn't previously tell you), it is pretty easy to just say *"sorry, I didn't want to assume - I suggest you include your title in future correspondence so that people will*

Comment: *know how to address you."* That seems to me to be the absolute safest option because if anyone is offended that you *didn't* assume something about them, then they are just going to get offended by a lot of benign things and you can't really do anything about that - whereas it is more reasonable for somebody to be offended if you *do* assume something about them which turns out to be incorrect. Of course, sometimes somebody's title can be inferred (rather than guessed), e.g. if somebody signs their email "Jane Doe PhD" then it is presumably safe to address them as Dr. Jane Doe.

Comment: There are many gender-ambiguous "traditional" names in the UK and US, and many more "modern inventions", For example Alex, Andy, Charlie, Hillary, Jackie, Jo, Leslie, Noel, Robin, etc.

Comment: If it's just email, do you even need the formality of a salutation?  I just go with "Hi," myself, if I use anything at all.

Comment: I like to maintain a little bit more formality when responding to someone I don't know, especially if I'm acting in an official capacity (e.g. as graduate chair; I didn't mention that in my question)

Comment: @Marc Glisse - There are huge cultural differences in this. Getting an informal reply to a formal email could be really offensive/distasteful to some. It could make them feel they are not taken seriously or are not respected.

Comment: as a non-binary person in the UK, what the wikipedia article is referring to is just that the government offers it as an option on dropdown lists online (and quite a few other large businesses have followed suit). Most people are still unfamiliar with it, or have just seen it as a vague curiosity. I've never experienced anyone using it for someone who's gender they do not know, only ever for people who have actively chosen to state that it is their title (usually because they are non-binary)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For a salutation in communications written in English, I would suggest using:

> Dear F. Doe,

or

> Dear Foo Doe,

These salutations seem pretty gender-neutral (gender-inclusive) and sound natural to my ear. They avoid any assumptions on the gender or title of the applicant. This is probably close to the form that you are currently using already.

Justification for this particular best practice: [Gender-inclusive writing: correspondence (Linguistic recommendation from the Translation Bureau, Government of Canada)](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/en/writing-tips-plus/gender-inclusive-writing-correspondence).

From the same source, it is clear that **a** "best practice" might change for communication in a different language. For French, they would recommend:

> Bonjour,

or name-specific:

> Foo Doe,

However, language dependence is just a side note for this particular question.

Other guidelines also exist, and if your educational institution or country has them, they are definitely worth taking a look at and considering for use. But choosing **some guideline that targets gender-inclusivity** is what one should do nowadays (unless something obviously flawed is discovered about a certain guide at some point).

Comment: Indeed, this is what I do when writing to editors of magazines, for instance...

Comment: I suppose it does assume you know which name is to be abbreviated, which can sometimes be unclear, e.g. with Chinese names, who sometime use native Chinese order (Family Given), and sometimes flip them to Western order. I'm not even sure if would be normal to call someone e.g. "Mao Z."

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- True. And then a "Dear Foo Doe," is perfectly good I guess.

Answer (score 97):

When responding to emails to people I have not met, I usually copy the name from the signature and add "Dear" in front.

Comment: This is the best answer - the simple principle is that somebody's name is what they tell you their name is.

Comment: Especially if it's unclear which part(s) of their signature would be "surname", or if that even makes sense.

Comment: This answer is good but I accepted @AntonMenshov's answer because it goes into a little bit more depth.

Comment: @BenBolker This answer is actually better because it works for people who only have one name.  I've gotten emails from Javanese students before.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononymous_person#Mononym-normal

Answer (score 20):

First, even in cases where you feel you can guess the gender, I suggest you to avoid using Mr or Ms because, first, there are exceptions that are easily misgendered and, second, you don't know the pronoun of the recipient. As an example of the former, Andrea in my country is a masculine name whereas in other countries is feminine. Many an Andrea has been misgendered along the years (a few years ago a former student of mine who had moved to Switzerland told me that he started signing off his emails as *Andreas* to avoid this).

Guessing which is the family name and which is the given one is also risky because in many Asian countries the family name is written first, but some people use the Western convention when writing to international recipients. In 2006, while organising a conference, I addressed many participants in the wrong way, until I realised about the exchange from the signature of someone I was familiar with.

So, in most cases, I've been using [Anton Menshov's](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/170958/20058) solution, with full name, for quite a while. For students, I also use

> Dear Student

A bit impersonal but safe.

Comment: In fact, it's happened numerous times in math that the author ordering has been non-alphabetical (our standard) because even collaborators confused family vs given names of East Asian coauthors! (see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/150414/19607)

Comment: Your former student, Andreas, may find that some people assume that's a female name too.  (Source: personal experience)

Comment: @AndreasBlass fwiw, that has never happened to me.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin: If I had to guess, it might be more common for people to wrongly assume "Andreas" is a female name in regions where "Andreas" isn't a common name in the first place but "Andrea" is.